# django tastypie - how to populate a nested resource which is not field in current resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a resource like this:

```
class User(ModelResource):
    friends = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, ....blah blah)
```

Where friends is not a field in the model User

But I want the friends to be listed in the api.

How to do that ?

Comment: Do you just want to list the users resource_uris in friends? You can write a dehydrate_friends where you build your response.

Comment: I tried this in TastyPie 0.14 @Deepak, but it results in an exception - 'NoneType' object is not iterable. It used to work in TastyPie 0.12.1 I believe.